# Multiple parallel actions in tkinter's button command

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I would like to add parallel actions in one button in tkinter window,  this is my main code

```
from Fonctions import *
from time import time, sleep
listConnextion = [a,b,c,d,e,f]

MotDePasse= ""

class ConnecOptimizerApp(tk.Tk):
def __init__(self):
    tk.Tk.__init__(self)
    tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self , default= "logo.ico")
    tk.Tk.wm_title(self,"ConnecOptimizer")
    container = tk.Frame(self)
    container.pack(side = "top", fill = "both", expand = True)
    self.frames ={}
    for f in  (PageAccueil, PageAttente):
        frame = f(container,self)
        self.frames[f] = frame
        frame.grid(row = 1000, column = 500, sticky = "nsew")
    self.show_frame(PageAccueil)

def show_frame(self,cont):
    frame = self.frames[cont]
    frame.tkraise()

class PageAccueil(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self,parent,controller):
    def cocher():
        if var4 == 0:
            ip.configure(state='disabled')
        else:
            ip.configure(state='normal')
    tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
    Frame0 = ttk.Frame(self)
    Frame0.pack(side="top")
    Frame1 = ttk.Frame(Frame0)
    Frame1.pack(side="left", padx=70, pady=50)
    Frame2 = ttk.Frame(Frame0)
    Frame2.pack(side="left", padx=10, pady=10)
    Frame3 = ttk.Frame(self)
    Frame3.pack(side="top")
    Frame4 = ttk.Frame(Frame3)
    Frame4.pack(side = "left")
    Frame5 = ttk.Frame(Frame3)
    Frame5.pack(side = "left")
    Fr = ttk.Frame(self).pack(side = "top")
    Frame6 = ttk.Frame(self)
    Frame6.pack(side = "top")
    Frame7 = ttk.Frame(Frame6)
    Frame7.pack(side="left")
    Frame8 = ttk.Frame(Frame6)
    Frame8.pack(side="left")
    Frame9 = ttk.Frame(self)
    Fr2 = ttk.Frame(self).pack(side = "top")
    Frame9.pack(side = "top")
    Frame10 = ttk.Frame(Frame9)
    Frame10.pack(side = "left")
    Frame11 = ttk.Frame(Frame9)
    Frame11.pack(side = "left")
    Frame12 = ttk.Frame(self)
    Frame12.pack(side = "top")
    varGr = tk.StringVar()
    varGr.set(0)
    for i in range(len(listConnextion)):
        b = ttk.Radiobutton(Frame1, variable=varGr, text=listConnextion[i], value=i)
        b.grid(row=i , sticky = "w")
    var1 = tk.IntVar()
    ttk.Checkbutton(Frame2, text="Graphique", variable=var1).grid(row=1 ,sticky = "w" )
    var2 = tk.IntVar()
    ttk.Checkbutton(Frame2, text="Diagnostic", variable=var2).grid(row=2 , sticky = "w")
    var3 = tk.IntVar()
    ttk.Checkbutton(Frame2, text="Optimisation", variable=var3).grid(row=3 , sticky = "w")
    lab = ttk.Label(Frame4, text = "Periode de reference de l'historique en jour ")
    lab.pack(side = "left" , padx = 30 )
    nbJour = ttk.Entry(Frame5)
    nbJour.pack(side = "left" )
    l = ttk.Label(Fr).pack()
    lab2 = ttk.Label(Frame7, text = "Nombre d'entrées pour finir l'apprentissage")
    lab2.pack(side = "left" , padx = 30)
    nbEntre = ttk.Entry(Frame8)
    nbEntre.pack(side = "left" )
    l2 = ttk.Label(Fr2).pack()
    var4 = tk.IntVar()
    ttk.Checkbutton(Frame10 , text = "Iperf", variable = var4 , command = cocher).pack( padx = 10)
    ip = ttk.Entry(Frame11 , state = 'disabled')
    ip.pack(padx = 20)
    B = ttk.Button(Frame12, text="Valider" , command = (lambda: controller.show_frame(PageAttente)))
    B.pack(side = "top" , pady = 30)

class PageAttente(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self,parent,controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
    frame0 = ttk.Frame(self)
    frame0.pack(side = "top")
    frame1 = ttk.Frame(self)
    frame1.pack(side = "top")
    self.T = tk.Text(frame0, height=20, width=53)
    self.S = ttk.Scrollbar(frame0)
    self.T.config(yscrollcommand=self.S.set)
    self.T.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.Y)
    self.S.config(command=self.T.yview)
    self.S.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
    self.updateWidgets()
    ttk.Button(frame1, text = "Arreter Diagnostic", command = (lambda : controller.show_frame(PageAccueil))  ).pack(pady = 10)

def updateWidgets(self):
    with open('text.txt') as f:
        newText = f.read()
    self.T.delete('1.0', tk.END)
    self.T.insert(tk.END, newText)
    self.after(1000, self.updateWidgets)


app = ConnecOptimizerApp()
app.geometry("450x400+300+140")
app.mainloop()
```

and here you can find my fonctions

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style

def PageLogin():
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("350x130+530+280")
root.title("Super-utilisateur")
def leave():
    MotDePasse = champMp.get()
    print(MotDePasse)
    root.destroy()
topFrame = ttk.Frame(root)
topFrame.pack()
middleFrame = ttk.Frame(root)
middleFrame.pack()
bottomFrame = ttk.Frame(root)
bottomFrame.pack()
lab1 = ttk.Label(topFrame, text=" ").pack()
lab2 = ttk.Label(topFrame, text="Veuillez entrer le mot de passe super-utilisateur").pack()
labelMessage2 = ttk.Label(middleFrame, text="mot de passe ")
labelMessage2.pack(side="left", padx=10, pady=10)
champMp = ttk.Entry(middleFrame, show='*')
champMp.pack(side="right", padx=10, pady=10)
b = ttk.Button(bottomFrame, text="valider", command = leave)
b.grid(row=4, pady=5, sticky="w")
root.mainloop()

def TracerGraphe ():
style.use('fivethirtyeight')
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

def animate(i):
    graph_data = open('test.txt', 'r').read()
    lines = graph_data.split('\n')
    xs = []
    ys = []
    zs = []
    ws = []
    for line in lines:
        if len(line) > 1:
            x, y, z, w = line.split(',')
            xs.append(x)
            ys.append(y)
            zs.append(z)
            ws.append(w)
    ax1.clear()
    ax2.clear()
    ax3.clear()
    ax1.plot(xs, ys, label='RTT')
    ax2.plot(xs, zs, label='Debit')
    ax3.plot(xs, ws, label='taux d erreur')
    ax1.legend()
    ax2.legend()
    ax3.legend()

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)
mngr = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
mngr.window.setGeometry(700, 100, 640, 545)
plt.show()
```

What I cant is : When I press the B button I want to show the PageAttente using "lambda: controller.show_frame(PageAttente)" , show the LoginPage using "PageLogin()" fonction and show the graph using "TracerGraphe ()"

I have tried all the solutions I found on net but it doesnt work

Can anyone help me please ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried multi threading? On the B button click put a function which creates 2 more threads, one for each function and start them (then call third function from this thread) and then join (wait till they all finish). That's it... you got parallel stuff in python. Documentation for python 3: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

Comment: It doesn't work


    class ParallelActions(Thread) :
    def __init__(self, q):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.param = q

    def run(self):
        """Code à exécuter pendant l'exécution du thread."""
        if self.param == 1 :
            PageLogin()
        elif self.param == 2 :
            TracerGraphe()

    def faire () :
    th = ParallelActions(1)
    th2 = ParallelActions(2)
    th.start()
    th2.start()
    th.join()
    th2.join()

Comment: Why do these functions need to be run in parallel?

Comment: All I need is : after clicking the B button , I want the PageLogin() window and the real time graph of TracerGraphe() to be shown in the same time ... I tried everything , the best thing I got is that TracerGraphe() works after closing the main window